# Normalized string alternative code for right answer

Tags: python, string, normalize

For a string, we want to make it all lower case and remain only alphabetical or space element.
The right answer is [image]

But for my code I think they are the same but did not work as well.
[image]

The first one is the right answer and the second one is my code. Could you help me figure out what happened? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement is nested inside the `for loop`, so it returns the value immediately.

You need to decrease the indentation of the `return` statement, so that the value is returned after the loop is completed.

Check [Python Reference Manual - 2.1.7 Indentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html)